# How do I compare two texts in perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 files:
1. a.txt
2. b.txt

a.txt:

```
UP_00292229  191
Xa_09833888  199
```

b.txt

```
UP_00292229  191
Xa_09833888  188
```

I want to compare this 2 files with the first column.

result:

```
UP_00292229 is same
Xa_09833888 is not same
```

How can I do it in perl?
How can I input 2 files at the same times?
How can I check the file format is xxxxx dddd (there is a space between xxxxx dddd)?

Comment: If you want to comapare these 2 files with first column, then the result you have mentioned is wrong, because both the column is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will compare `first column` of both files and if value matches it will print `same` otherwise `not same`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
open ( my $file2,"<", "b.txt" ) or die $!;
while ( my $line = <$file2> )
{
   chomp ( $line );
   my ($column3, $column4) = split ' ', $line;
   $seen{$column3}++;
}
close ( $file2 );

open ( my $file1, "<", "a.txt" ) or die $!; 
while ( my $line1 = <$file1> )
{
   chomp $line1;
   my ($column1, $column2) = split ' ', $line1;
   print $column1, " ", $seen{$column1} ? "is same" : "is not same", "\n";
}
close ( $file1 );
```

Comment: but How can I check the file format is xxxxx dddd (there is a space between xxxxx dddd)??
thanks

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to do with file format and what is this xxxxx dddd? Better explain your need clearly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409254/how-do-i-check-a-format-of-input-file/29409331#29409331

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $handle_file1,"<","file1";
open my $handle_file2,"<","file2";

my @ar = <$handle_file1>;
my @br = <$handle_file2>;

for my $i(0..$#ar){

    if($ar[$i] eq $br[$i]){
        chomp $ar[$i];
        print "$ar[$i] is same\n";
    }
    else{
        chomp $ar[$i];
        print "$ar[$i] is not same\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will compare files with all columns.