# how do I check a format of input file

Tags: perl

I have a file:

```
aaaa ddd
aaaa ddd
```

I want to check the format: `aaaa(string) dddd(string)`
there is only one space between aaaa and dddd

for example:

```
 aaaa ddd
aaaa ddd
```

or

```
aaaaddd
aaaa ddd
```

both are wrong.
the size of string is not considerable...
how do I write it in perl?

Comment: Why is `aaaa ddd` wrong format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to check that every line in your file has exactly two strings (non-whitespace-characters?), separated by exactly one space. Looking at your first example, there also shouldn't be any space before the first string.

The regex you need should look something like this:

```
$line =~ /^\S+ \S+$/
```

\S stands for any non-whitespace character. If you can specify the allowable characters more closely, other character classes are available.

To check this for every line, loop over the file:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    if ($line !~ /^\S+ \S+$/) {
        print "line $line has format error!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

read a file line by line and then check with regexp

```
$line =~ /^a{4}\sd{3}$/
```